# Magento2 - Modify surrounding divs of layouts

Tags: magento2, xml, page-layouts

I'm using the 2columns-left as a layout for my category pages and I want to modify these divs, change their classes, without having to add javascript afterwards. I can already modify the templates that handle the content inside thoses divs, I just want to change these divs' classes.

```
<div class="columns> <!-- where is this generated ? -->
    <div class="column main"> <!-- where is this generated ? -->
     ...
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar sidebar-main"> <!-- where is this generated ? -->
     ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't seem to find a solution to this problem. I have looked around in the vendor module looking for some kind of meta-layout, but I'm not actually sure what I should be looking for. Can you help ?

Answer (score 0):

These class are defined in the vendor/module-theme/view/frontend/page_layout/2columns-left.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="columns">
    <container name="div.sidebar.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-main" after="main">
        <container name="sidebar.main" as="sidebar_main" label="Sidebar Main"/>
    </container>
    <container name="div.sidebar.additional" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-additional" after="div.sidebar.main">
        <container name="sidebar.additional" as="sidebar_additional" label="Sidebar Additional"/>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

If you want to modify on the category pages only its better to make a new category layout.xml file and there reference this container and change its content.

For this create a file if doesn't exist in app/design/frontend/Theme_Vendor/Theme_Name/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

Reference this columns container like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="columns">
        <---- Add your updated content here ----->
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

And if you want to implement this using your custom module then create the same file mention above in app/code/Vendor/extension/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml and follow the same.

Comment: What about the "column main" div ? Why is it not inside the layout ?
Also, in the original 2columns-left file, there is     handle=1column    and this makes my layout act as a single column. When I remove that line, the layout crashed and returns a blank page

Comment: As all the page layouts file extends the empty.xml, this class is defined in this xml file. you can find this xml in vendor/module-theme/view/base/page_layout/empty.xml

Comment: Also you can update this whole column container in your custom module by adding a catalog_category_view.xml and there reference this "columns" container like I gave you above and change the all the contents in this container.

Comment: Did it helped.?

Comment: Currently working on it, seems to be what I was looking for. If you don't mind, I'll accept the answer once I manage to make everything work ^^

Comment: Sure, let me know if I can help you more.

Comment: Actually yes. 
What if I want to keep the content of the column referenced container, and not rewrite it ?

Comment: If you just want to update the classes of these containers you can do it like in the catalog_category_view.xml in custom module or your theme

<referenceContainer name="div.sidebar.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="add your new classes here"></referenceContainer>

<referenceContainer name="div.sidebar.additional" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="add your new classes here"></referenceContainer>

<referenceContainer name="main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="add your new classes here"></referenceContainer>

Comment: Thing is, there is no reference to these containers inside catalog_category_view.xml, and if I add a new referenceContainer, it empties the whole container

Comment: Then rewriting is the best option you have. In your theme check which theme is the parent of it, open that theme, go to its catalog_category_view.xml and copy these containers from there. and update the classes.

to check the parent theme go to app/design/vendor/theme/theme.xml and check in the <parent> tag.

Comment: Did this solved your issue.?

Comment: No, sorry for not answering sooner. I did find a solution to my problem, I'll post it when I get access to my code, next week